# How do I set the Button Element so that they can be controlled with arrow keys?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm working on a Manual Image gallery/slideshow, where pressing the pointers will take you to the next/previous image. I've created the pointers using the 'Button' element. Now I just want users to be able to use the left/right arrow keys as well.

To make the 'button' elements work I'm using javascript.

```
<button class="left" onclick="plusDivs(-1)">&#10094;</button>
<button class="right" onclick="plusDivs(+1)">&#10095;</button>


<script>
var slideIndex = 1;
showDivs(slideIndex);

function plusDivs(n) {
    showDivs(slideIndex += n);
}

function showDivs(n) {
    var i;
    var x = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
    if (n > x.length) {
        slideIndex = 1
    }
    if (n < 1) {
        slideIndex = x.length
    }
    for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
        x[i].style.display = "none";
    }
    x[slideIndex - 1].style.display = "block";
}
</script>
```

I'm not sure where to start since I've never used javascript, and have not found much useful info so far. Hoping someone can push me in the right direction.

Answer (score 2):

You will need to add an event listener to the window object which is universal in internet browsers. Browser events like "click" and such bubble up from the element they affected all the way to the window.

As far as I know keystroke are directly applied to the window. You will need to add a listener and listen for the corresponding key text. I use key text instead of keycode as I find it more semantic. Use console.log(e) to explore the keydown event. Google around for compatibility use cases depending on what browsers you need to support.

```
window.addEventListener("keydown", (e) => {
   if (e.key === "ArrowLeft"){
      plusDivs(-1);
   } else if (e.key === "ArrowRight"){
      plusDivs(1);
   }
}
```

It appears you are using inline function calls embedded in your html. Since standard listener binding is done via script and not inline html you will need to place the above listener in a DOMContenLoaded Listener.... this usually wraps all your javascript code in your script and executes it... rather than manually executing your functions.

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    ...above code goes here...
    ...including all your existing code...
});
```

PS. You don't need to do +1 ... just 1 as it is already a positive integer.

Comment: Thank you very much! I just want to make sure is this something I add as an external file/document? if so how how does it 'connect' to the html document? I don't know the formatting and I'm not finding much on it.

Comment: It's javascript, it goes inside your script tag from your question.